# jQuery Lite / AngularJS: How to add a class to a single child of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add an active class to an element using AngularJS's jQuery Lite library and I'm having trouble.

I was hoping I could do something like `element.children()[index].addClass('active');` however, the following error is returned:

`TypeError: element.children(...)[index].addClass is not a function`

Is there a way to add a class to a single child of an element?

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('rugapp')
    .directive('menu', menu);

    menu.$inject = ['$location'];

    function menu($location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
      };

      function link(scope, element) {

        scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
          angular.forEach(element.children(), function(link, index) {
            if (link.hash.replace('#', '') === $location.path()) {
              console.log("Make " + $location.path() + " active!!!");
              console.log(element.children()[index]);
              // element.children()[index].addClass('class');
            }
          });
        });

      }
    }

})();
```

For completeness, this directive is applied like so:

```
<div class="list-group" menu>
  <a href="app/#/" class="list-group-item">Home</a>
  <a href="app/#/link1" class="list-group-item">Link1</a>
  <a href="app/#/link2" class="list-group-item">Link2</a>
  ....
</div>
```

UPDATE: Working directive to add an 'active' class using an AngularJS directive.

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('rugapp')
    .directive('menu', menu);

    menu.$inject = ['$location'];

    function menu($location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
      };

      function link(scope, element) {

        scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
          angular.forEach(element.children(), function(link, index) {
            if (link.hash.replace('#', '') === $location.path()) {
              element.children().eq(index).addClass('active');
            } else {
              element.children().eq(index).removeClass('active');
            }
          });
        });

      }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, what you want to do is this

```
element.children().eq(index).addClass('active');
```

Note that eq() is zero-based. So selecting the first child, you end up with this

```
element.children().eq(0).addClass('active');
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: This is a pretty fickle solution - what if I wanted, for styling purposes, to add `<span> | </span>` (for example) - that would break this solution immediately. @RaphaelRafatpanah

Comment: @NewDev, Interesting. Is there a way to restrict the above statement to only include `a` elements?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah, even that is fickle. What if you wanted to change it `<button>` or what if you had another `<a>` not related to navigation?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of enumerating child DOM elements and finding/extracting the anchors that link to a different "route" (I presume you are using routes here, although it doesn't matter) is very fickle. Let alone, assume (as your approach suggested) that there are *only* `<a>` child elements.

What if you decided to use `<button>` instead? What if you had other non-menu related `<a>` or other styling components? Any modification to the DOM break your approach.

Instead, I suggest you follow what [`angular-ui` did with `ui-sref-active`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) does ([src](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/b1ebd261cb2d24807b666a198846687eff2c6b10/src/stateDirectives.js#L228)). It only works with `ui.router`, obviously, but the idea is the same: it applies an "active" style to each directive based on the matching "state".

So, a conceptual solution for you could be:

```
.directive("menuActive", function($location, $interpolate){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

      var activeClass = $interpolate(attrs.menuActive)(scope);

      // for simplicity of example, I assume that it only applies 
      // to <a href="url#hash">, but you could make it generic
      if (element[0].tagName !== "A") return;
      var link = element[0];

      $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function()
        if (link.hash.replace('#', '') === $location.path()){
           element.addClass(activeClass);
        } else {
           element.removeClass(activeClass);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

and the usage is:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="app/#/"      menu-active="active" class="list-group-item">Home</a>
  <a href="app/#/link1" menu-active="active" class="list-group-item">Link1</a>
  <a href="app/#/link2" menu-active="active" class="list-group-item">Link2</a>
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Even easier might be to just use ng-class.

Comment: @jme11, it's possible, but hardly easier... You need to activate a class only when something matches the location - so you could have some logic in `ng-class`, but that pollutes the View